# Symfony2.4 Date Validation not working

Tags: validation, date, symfony

I need some validations done, for example, in a date field. I've configured config.sml and config_dev.xml to enable annotations as told in docs. Here is my code:

Entity:

```
/** *************************************************
 * @var date
 *
 * @Assert\Date(message="Fecha de Nacimiento incorrecta")
 * @ORM\Column(name="dfec_nacimiento", type="date", nullable=true)
 */
private $fecNacimiento;

/**
 * @param date $fecNacimiento
 */
public function setFecNacimiento($fecNacimiento)
{
    $this->fecNacimiento = $fecNacimiento;
}

/**
 * @return date
 * @Assert\Date()
 */
public function getFecNacimiento()
{
    return $this->fecNacimiento;
}
```

Controller:

```
[..]
                $form = $this->createForm(new IncidenciaType($numSocio,
                                                             null,
                                                             $listadoTiposIncidencia,
                                                             $listadoCentros,
                                                             $listadoTiposDoc,
                                                             $listadoTiposVia),
                                          $incidencia);
                $form->handleRequest($request);//bind del formulario con el request
                if ($form->isValid()) {
                //Some code
                } else {
                  } else {
                    $errors = array();

                    if ($form->count() > 0) {
                        foreach ($form->all() as $child) {
                            /**
                             * @var \Symfony\Component\Form\Form $child
                             */
                            if (!$child->isValid()) {
                                $errors[$child->getName()] = $this->getErrorMessages($child);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        /**
                         * @var \Symfony\Component\Form\FormError $error
                         */
                        foreach ($form->getErrors() as $key => $error) {
                            $errors[] = $error->getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                    //$errores = array('1' => 'Existen errores en los datos');
                    return $this->render('Bundle:Environment:registro.html.twig',
                                         array('form' => $form->createView(),
                                               'errores' => $errors));
                }
```

Form:

```
->add('fecNacimiento','date', array('widget' => 'single_text',
                                                'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                                                'invalid_message' => 'Debe introducir una fecha válida',
                                                'label' => 'Fecha nacimiento: '))
```

I'm getting no errors messages when user puts aninvalid date, for example, 121/05/2000 (dd/mm/yyyy format), but $for->isValid() is returning false. But when user puts 77/05/2000, it's working wrong, inserting a date in database adding 77 days to 01/05/2000.

Where I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you solve your problem? In that case, share your solution please.

Comment: I've just tested this solution but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

You could try to solve this adding the 'input' option to the options array:

```
->add('fecNacimiento','date', 
            array('widget' => 'single_text',
                  'format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
                  'invalid_message' => 'Debe introducir una fecha válida',
                  'label'  => 'Fecha nacimiento: ',
                  'input'  => 'datetime' ))
```

Comment: Using 'input'  => 'datetime' is not working. Is still accepting date like 65/04/2003...